# Allowed characters in php-fpm pool name

Tags: php, php-fpm, php.ini

php-fpm allows to configure individual pools.

```
[poolname]
user = ...
group = ...
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
...
```

Which characters are allowed within the square brackets in the first line?

Answer (score 2):

I also could not find the answer anywhere, therefore started experimenting.
It turned out that there are no strict limitation on this matter, I was able to run fpm pool with the following names:

```
[domaincom]
[domain.com]
[*.domain.com]
```

and even

```
[Domain: *.domain.com Root: /var/www]
```

So fpm pool name can be the same as the domain name for convenience, especially while reviewing process tree.